# Microsoft Cognitive Services Translator API remaining characters

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator

Is there a way to get the remaining character allocation for a Translator API subscription in the **new Azure Portal**, similar to how we could previously using the My Data page on Microsoft Datamarket?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do this with Consumption API:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt219001

If you want to view it in the portal, then the only thing I could find is this:

https://translatorbusiness.uservoice.com/forums/553099-microsoft-translator-on-azure-customer-question-fo/suggestions/17379046-subscription-statistic-api-method

Not sure if it will help though.

> When you are subscribed to the Microsoft Translator Text or Speech API
>   on Azure, you can get a day-by-day report of your consumption. There
>   is a 24-hour delay between the actual consumption and when it is
>   displayed in the report.
>
> To view the report:  1) Visit
>   https://account.windowsazure.com/Subscriptions  2) Choose the name of
>   your Azure subscription  3) Choose "Download usage details"  4) Choose
>   "Download usage"
>
> You will receive a CSV file containing your daily consumption, one
>   line per day per service.
>
> To see the Microsoft Translator API consumption, filter by Meter
>   Category = Cognitive Services.
>
> You can also get a graph for the current billing period, in the
>   Overview section.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly I was looking for a way to use the online dashboard/ portal to get a quick glimpse of my remaining character allocation, similar to how we could before using the Datamarket. And it doesn't seem that is possible at this time. Hopefully they'll add it soon.

Comment: Unfortunately the Azure Translation Consumptions or remaining characters are not listed in the Concumption API

Answer (score -1):

In Cognitive Services, you are paying-as-you-go. There is no max quota, like in the Data Market days where you purchased a certain number of characters for the month.

Comment: I think you are mistaken, the Cognitive Services Translator Text API has several tiers each with an allocation of characters per month, in addition to a pay-as-you-go plan. But regardless, it'd be beneficial to see how many characters you've used so far this month both for analytics purposes and to manage your expenses.

Comment: I don't disagree that it's useful to know what is spent. But the various tiers in Cognitive Services provide a certain amount per month e.g 1B for $6k. But if you reach 1B, you can keep using the service at $8.22 per 1M vs in DataMarket days, the service would refuse to translate, at any price, until you bought another package using Data Market or the month rolled over. So Cognitive Services will switch from prepaid to pay-as-you-go if you exceed your paid-for limit.

Comment: Thank you for the information, that's useful to know. However it does not solve my question. To rephrase: I would like a way to see the current usage statistics for a Translator API subscription in the Cognitive Services Azure portal.